# How to set Media Cache Folder per site?

Tags: media-library, caching, multisite

**Context**

In my Sitecore (8.2.u7) instance I have 2 websites that share the same images.
For this reason, I have setup `Media.MediaLinkServerUrl` e.g. cdn.mysite.com.
This will also help me to integrate with an external CDN provider.

I have also created a virtual Directory named "MediaCache" inside \App_Data\
that points to a local path. (for internal reasons)

**Objectives**

I want to setup both sites to use the same cache folder e.g. \App_data\MediaCache\Common

**Actions**

I tried with the following settings:

- (Sitecore setting) `Media.CacheFolder` = "/App_Data/MediaCache"
- (site) `mediaCachePath` = "/App_Data/MediaCache/Common"

But the result was the images to be stored under a "website" folder that actually points to the default "website" Sitecore site. ("/App_data/MediaCache/website")

The only thing I can think is that because I have specified an url for the media library items and there is no relevant site for them, then they are stored under the default website.

**Question**

Is this true or I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: While we don't have an external CDN or use a virtual directory we're using mediaCachePath="/App_Data/MediaCache/SharedFolder" in our site configs to share media caching between sites on 8.2, so you might need a support ticket from Sitecore